# why delete button in jframe java error

Tags: java, jframe

I tried tutorial on youtube
I create the delete button in jframe java, then when I run an error occurs

```
 private void btnDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   if (!jtextId.getText().equals(""))
   {
       try {
           Connection con = getConnection();
           PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM product WHRRE id = ?");
           int id=Integer.parseInt(jtextId.getText());
           ps.setInt(1, id);
           ps.executeUpdate();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Delete");

       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Main_Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Produt Not Deleted");
       }

   }
   else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Product");
   }
}
```

On the output error is in `ps.executeUpdate();`

What should I fix??

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code you pasted is your actual code, the error come from this line:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM product WHRRE id = ?");
```

You have a typo error in your SQL, replace by:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM product WHERE id = ?");
```